# Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available

Tags: managed-metadata

If I go to Term store Management "Site Settings  Term Store Management Tool" I get the following error.

> The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available.
>   The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been
>   started. Please Contact your Administrator.

In addition my event viewer has errors like the following.  In the end I am trying to edit wiki categories on a wiki publishing site which relies on management meta data.

Any ideas???

WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/33711845
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/securitytoken.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The farm is unavailable.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your app pool "SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool" is Started. Also check other application pools where identity is set to network service.

I just stop this app pool and got same error.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see whether the Managed Metadata Service is actually running. Also see whether you can access it from central admin (could be a security issue where your webapp isn't authorised to talk to the Managed Metadata Service).